# WinForms - Text Not Being Set or Set After Sleep

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino

I've just recently started learning how to develop Windows Forms applications. I've been programming in C# for a couple years now (within Unity3D).

I am currently developing an HMI (Human Machine Interface) application that connects to an Arduino. I already have it working; ie: I can connect to it and read from/write to the Arduino. So, this following code WORKS (as far as communication is concerned).

```
private void ConnectToArduino () {
    labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connecting...";

    string selectedPort = comboBoxMonitorComPorts.GetItemText (comboBoxMonitorComPorts.SelectedItem);
    port = new SerialPort (selectedPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    try {
        port.Open ();

        while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
            port.ReadByte ();

        port.Write ("CPU0CN\n");

        Thread.Sleep (3000);

        if (port.BytesToRead > 0) {
            String response = port.ReadLine ();

            if (response.Equals ("test")) {
                labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connected";
                btnMonitorConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
                isConnected = true;

                EnableControls ();
            }
            else {
                labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connection Failed!";
                btnMonitorConnect.Text = "Connect";
                isConnected = false;

                port.Close ();
                ResetControls ();
            }
        }
        else {
            labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connection Failed!";
            btnMonitorConnect.Text = "Connect";
            isConnected = false;

            port.Close ();
            ResetControls ();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connection Failed!";
        btnMonitorConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

        ResetControls ();
    }
}
```

That code successfully connects me to the Arduino through a serial com port. Let's focus on this section of the code:

```
labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connecting...";

string selectedPort = comboBoxMonitorComPorts.GetItemText (comboBoxMonitorComPorts.SelectedItem);
port = new SerialPort (selectedPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

try {
    port.Open ();

    while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
        port.ReadByte ();

    port.Write ("CPU0CN");

    Thread.Sleep (3000);
```

`labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connecting...";`
Set the text on *labelMonitorConnectionStatus* to "Connecting..."

`port.Open ();`
Open the port...

`port.Write ("CPU0CN\n");`
Write communication startup request message through com port

`Thread.Sleep (3000);`
Wait 3 seconds for response from com port (will reduce this later, of course)

This should change the text to "Connecting...", then wait 3 seconds before being changed to either "Connection Failed!" or "Connected". However, that isn't happening. What's happening instead is the Thread will sleep for 3 seconds—without having set the text to "Connecting..."—then immediately change to either "Connection Failed!" or "Connected". In other words, I never see "Connecting..." on the application. I see "Not Connected" for 3 seconds, then "Connection Failed!" or "Connected".

[Watch this short clip to understand what I see](https://youtu.be/41T0Aw269-A)

Thanks, in advance, for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows will handle all events in order when it sees a change to do it, not after every statement you call. So your sleep command will interfere with updating the label

try with calling an update command on the label right after setting its text.

```
labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connecting...";
labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Update();
```

If that does not helps, update the entire form like this

```
labelMonitorConnectionStatus.Text = "Connecting...";
Update();
```

Comment: Updating just the Label object's text only seems to draw over the existing text (most of the time). However, updating the entire form actually replaces the text and displays properly.

Thank you for the help!